# jquery Chunked Fileupload: Handle Server Side Error

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the error handling to work for chunked file upload using blueimps jquery fileupload.

I have the following code, in which when a server side error occures, the error method never gets hit:

```
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        maxFileSize: 50 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000,
        maxChunkSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024,
        singleFileUploads: true,
        sequentialUploads: true,
        add: function (e, data) {

            var jqXHR = data.submit()
                .success(function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    debugger;
                    var url = "/Upload.ashx?SetId=@Model.SetId&filename=" + result[0].name + "&ct=" + result[0].type + "&multiUpload=complete";
                    url = encodeURI(url);
                    $.ajax(url);
                })
                .error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                })
                .complete(function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    //alert("complete");
                });
        }

    });
```

Neither when I return json like  {"error","Error with the extension of the file"} with an Http 200 response, nor a http 500, make the code hit the above error method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to handle jQuery ajax method error.

```
 $.ajax(url).success(function(){
             })
            .error(function(){});
```